# How to use parse command line argument with SST simulator?

Tags: python, cpu-architecture

I am trying to learn SST (Structural Simulation Toolkit). When I try to run exercise 2 (https://github.com/sstsimulator/sst-tutorials/tree/master/exercises/ex2) with this command **sst --config=miranda.cfg ex2.py**, terminal keeps giving the error **sst: unrecognized option '--config=miranda.cfg'**. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two ways to accomplish this. The first option defines a a set of model options in which all parameters are listed within a single quotation bounded region. Such as:

```
$ sst --model-options="--param0=X --param1=Y" myModel.py
```

Alternatively you can separate your model from the parameter list but adding a "--" between them such as can be seen below:

```
$ sst myModel.py -- --param0=X --param1=Y
```

Take note that the parameters are used in the same manner regardless of the inclusion method written. what I mean by this is that  the parameter must have something such as "--" followed by the parameter name, "param0" for example, and then the value that parameter is to contain "=".

For example 2 from the standard SST Tutorials we can take a look at the relevant contents of ex2.py.

```
.
.
.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--config", help="specify configuration file", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase verbosity of output", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--statfile", help="statistics file", default="./stats.csv")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--statlevel", help="statistics level", type=int, default=16)

args = parser.parse_args()

verbose = args.verbose
cfgFile = args.config
statFile = args.statfile
statLevel = args.statlevel
.
.
.
```

Essentially what we are creating here is an associative array called **parser** in which the keys are the parameter string such as "-c" or "--config". When we include those strings python knows to take whatever is entered after the "-c=" and put it into the value slot for the array element matching the key of "-c". You can have any arbitrary number of these parameters, and since we are using an associative array that matches based on the key and not the array element number, it doesn't matter which order the parameters are listed in the command line.

One other thing to mention here is that if you look at the parameter list we have the last element in the is the default value. If you do not include this parameter at runtime this is the value that will be used by default.

Getting back to your specific question, you want to use the configuration file called  "miranda.cfg". To do this your command line sequence to do this for ex2.py would be

```
sst --model-options="--config=miranda.cfg" ex2.py
```

Further reading on how to run SST simulations, including the source for this answer, can be found at http://sst-simulator.org/SSTPages/SSTUserHowToRunSST/